# How to import adjacency matrix for network in netlogo

Tags: matrix, social-networking, netlogo, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix lets say for example

> 0 1 0 1 0 1
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 0
>
> 0 1 1 0 1 1
>
> 0 1 1 1 0 1
>
> 0 0 0 1 0 1
>
> 0 1 0 1 0 1

The matrix is 6x6 matrix because I have 6 agents.

I would like to import this matrix to `netlogo`.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: the matrix is 6x6 matrix because i have 6 agents

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nw:load-matrix`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#load-matrix) from the built-in nw extension.

You use it like so:

```
nw:load-matrix "/path/to/matrix/file" turtles directed-links
```

where `directed-links` is a directed links breed (I specified directed here since, from your adjacency matrix, it looks like you're dealing with a directed network).